# Android - is there any Function or Way to Search a specific text in an HTML Webview text

Tags: java, android, webview, textview

Hello to all Android Programmers, is there any way to search a specific word in an HTML Webview? Or lets say when you put a word in search  box and search it and then it will automatically scroll to the word or highlight it but the text is not in TextView the text are formatted using WebView? Sure it may be possible when you store a paragraph in the database and it can be searched easily but the problem on it is it isn't formatted like HTML so is this possible?
[Please see the image on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UeBZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
For Highlighting search word:

    titleWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (searchText != null && !searchText.equals("")) {
                int i = titleWebView.findAll(searchText);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found " + i + " results !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
                    m.invoke(titleWebView, true);
                } catch (Throwable ignored) {
                }
                searchText = "";
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The OP is asking if there's a way to search for a text in a WebView so that the searched term appears highlighted, not how to make an HTTP request and convert the result to string.

Comment: as i mention above that if we get the data from html in string form than we simple check that if that string contains particular word or not

Comment: But the OP is asking how to search for a word and `**automatically scroll to the word or highlight it**` in the WebView.  Simply checking if the HTML string contains a particular word or not, will not hightlight the word in WebView.

Comment: thank you for your effort on replying on my question. I'm gonna try this method. Thank you very much all of you. God Bless

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by reading `source` of page in webview.

Inside

> Add this method in onPageFinished() of webviewclient:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+" +
                                        "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
```

> Declaration for above called method processHTML() which helps to
>   process source html to String/JSON Obj.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @JavascriptInterface
        public String processHTML(final String html)
        {
//            Log.i("processed html",html);
            Thread OauthFetcher=new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    htmlString= Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
//                    Log.i("htmlString",htmlString);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    CustomPojoObject obj = gson.fromJson(htmlString, CustomPojoObject.class);

                }
            });OauthFetcher.start();
            return htmlString;
        }
```